# performance problems on a Cloud hosting account

Tags: magento-1.9, performance, cloud, memory-leak

I have installed the newest version of the Magento shopping cart 1.9.1 and we are having serious performance problems (extremely high load, server running out of memory...)

Is there something we can do to improve performance? Is the following hardware/software sufficient? (they keep saying that Magento is known for being memory usage intensive and we should upgrade but I'm already paying $60/month for this)

```
vCPUs/Ghz  2 / 1.8Ghz
Dedicated RAM  2048MB
Cloud Storage  60GB 
Bandwidth     2000GB
Operating System    linux
Perl Version    5.10.1
Apache Version  2.2.29 
PHP Version     5.5.24
MySQL Version   5.6.23
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! ;-)

Comment: What are your MYSQL settings?, How many products do you have? How many visitors are you getting?

Comment: please tell us your traffic stats and output from `top | head -n 5 `

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something we can do to improve performance? Is the following hardware/software sufficient?

**vCPUs/Ghz  2 / 1.8Ghz**

No, your CPU clock speed is extremely slow. A 3.5GHz CPU is going to outperform a 1.8GHz CPU by a factor of 2.

```
CPU Speed      Page Load Time (seconds)
3.5            0.480
3.4            0.495
3.3            0.510
3.2            0.525
3.1            0.540
3              0.555
2.9            0.570
2.8            0.585
2.7            0.600
2.6            0.615
2.5            0.630
2.4            0.645
2.3            0.660
2.2            0.675
2.1            0.690
```

**Dedicated RAM  2048MB**

You don't have nearly enough RAM. At an absolute minimum, a Magento server should have at least 8GB of RAM to run properly.

Depending on your catalogue size and traffic levels, the RAM requirement is going to increase.

**Cloud Storage  60GB**

Whilst the storage capacity isn't an issue, the storage backend probably is. Anything in "the cloud" is inherently slow due to contented resources (shared disk/networking/hypervisors).

Under normal circumstances (ie. on a dedicated server), a typical Magento store isn't bound by I/O. It doesn't require *fast* disks (eg. HDDs work just as well as SSDs), but in a cloud environment, the sheer overhead of the storage infrastructure can cause extremely significant disk I/O issues.

***Sources***

- https://www.sonassihosting.com/help/magestack/cpu-sizing/
- https://www.sonassihosting.com/help/magestack/ram-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

What they are saying is true. Magento unfortunately really resource hungry system. Something around $60/month won't be sufficient I believe.

Still there are few things you can do:

1. Enable all caching services
2. Enable `js and css` merger from `system > Configuration > Developer > Javascript Settings/Css Settings`

If still not enough!

3. Use `Redis or any other full page` caching (you might need to buy extension for this unless you develop it)

Still not enough then simply upgrade your server.

Comment: I recomment Varnish, and it is free

Comment: you dont even know what the problem is.